Do tags for specific countries make sense?
I have just been scanning the newest tags and we now have bulgaria, australia, uk, eu, and probably a bunch more. 
As far as I understand, we consider questions about "how to buy coins in specific countries" as asking for "product recommendations". On the other hand, legal questions are usually met with the suggestion for the asker to seek out legal advice. 
What would then be any valid case in which those tags should be applied?

The only real use case I could see is countries making the news themselves when it comes to crypto currencies. For instance, Hong Kong indicating that they don't find them legitimate, or perhaps if a country tried to block / outlaw the use of them (great wallet of China?)
At that point, they become relevant. Otherwise, they (as you noted) tend to lead to smells.

I'll see that I add them to my review then, all of the above actually seem to be smelly.
